# Is it possible to control WiFi/Hotspot/Bluetooth features via application on iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, wifi, hotspot

Is it possible to gain control, over any one of the following features, via an app on iOS/Android:

- turn on/off WiFi/Hotspot/BT
- read/write the device Hotspot/BT name, as it is seen by peer devices
- refresh available Hotspot/BT networks and read their names - while app runs in background / foreground

You can imagine where I am going with this - an all-in-one WiFi/Hotspot/BT manager app that would be similar in look-and-feel on both iOS and Android.

In case some of this has constraints in specific iOS/Android versions - please mention that.

Comment: It's better to ask "how to" rather than "can it be done" because the answer to the latter is just going to be "yes" or "no" which is not very helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done on Android. It can't be done in iOS.

Comment: You should qualify your answer as to platform(s). On iOS the answer is no, it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, the answer is "No, it can't be done"

Comment: You can't control any BT/HotSpot/WiFi features or you can't control most?

Comment: You can't control any

Comment: It's not possible at all. No. None.

Answer (score -1):

In Android :YES, you can have a full control.